# Add " Ask a question" component in 'Customer account portal"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community-builder, lightning-community

I have to add a button that says "Ask a question" which will redirect me to another page in the customer account portal. However, I cannot find "Ask a question" component in customer account template as it is only available under "Napili Template". Is there a way to get it from the other templates or do I have to build a new component?

Answer (score 1):

The ask a question button simply opened a modal which allowd users to post FeedItem QuestionPosts to the community.

[image]

If you want a button that redirects to X page with a label "Ask a Question" you will have to create your component (which is very straightforward and can easily be achieved)

for example:

component.cmp

```
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Ask A Question" onclick="{! c.handleRedirect}" />
```

component.js

```
handleRedirect: function (component, event, helper) {
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": "/CommunityUrl"
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```